# parallelization strategy for multiple sums in C with MPI

Tags: c, mpi

My question regards how a problem of parallelizing multiple sums should be approached in MPI. Namely, suppose one wants to compute the following quantity

[image]

where for example for two variables you may have

[image]

where I have chosen an arbitrary function for clarity. (hopefully)

What is the best way to divide the variables between the processes? I know how to parallelize a single sum

[image]

by dividing the sum on `p` processes with some local index and then by putting all together with `MPI_Reduce();` at the end.

The problem with multiple sums is that the sum in x1 needs all the possible values of all the other variables x2...xN so I cannot simply divide the sums in blocks on different processes since all the blocks are needed by all the others. Naively it seems that only one sum may be parallelized.

However, if one could make the different sums comunicate between the processes such that the sums on x2...xN could be sent to the sum on x1 and vice versa maybe all the sums could be parallelized. Can this be implemented in practice without creating major bottlenecks? Is there a better way?

I hope this question is in acceptable form, I am asking about how the problem should be approached theoretically.

Comment: I do not understand your formula (but I perfectly understand http://www.columbia.edu/itc/sipa/math/summation.html fwiw). I suggest you clarify your question and/or give what you expect from a simple example.

Comment: thanks for the edit. if `L1 <= p` then it does not matter whether you have one or multiple sums. If not, you can parallelize on `max(L1, ..., Ln)`. And if you have some unused MPI tasks, you can split on several indexes. In any case, I do not see any redundancy or need to communicate except a single reduce at the end. makes sense ?

Comment: I am sorry but not sure what do you mean by  this comment. You are saying that only one sum can be parallelized?

Comment: oops, I meant `p <= L1` ! you can parallelize anything you want, and this does not require any communication except the final reduce.